# Bash, variables and arrays

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I crawled through lots of boards but didn't find the final solution for my problem.

I have got an array, named "array0", the name is stored to a variable called `arrayname`. Also I've got a logged IP address, let's say 127.0.0.1, also stored in a variable, called ip.

Now I want to assign the IP to index 3 in the array like that:

```
"$arrayname"[3]="$ip"
```

So, this didn't work. I tried lots of ways how to solve that but none worked.
Is anyone out there who can tell me the final solution for this case?

**Update:** The given opportunities to handle the problem are great! But I forgot to mention that the array I'm working with is just sourced from another file (also written in bash). My goal is now to edit the array in the sourced file itself. Any more ideas for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
read ${arrayname}[3] <<<"$ip"
```

Comment: +1 I always forget you can read into elements of an array as well.

Comment: Nice. I can't decide whether I like this `read` method or chepner's `declare` method better. But both are miles ahead of an eval-based approach. :)

Comment: yeah, thanks, this worked great! my problem now, what i've forgot to tell: the array is stored in another file I accessed with the source command.. there the array is declared by 'declare -a array0', then 0-2 are filled like 'array0=(value0 value1 value2). How can I print the values into the array in the other file?

Comment: @dncrft : Do you mean you want to modify the text of the sourced file itself? You should edit your new requirements into your question, or maybe start a new question.

Comment: You can't handle variables that contain newlines. Unless you do some trickery like `IFS= read -r -d '' "$arrayname[3]" < <(printf '%s' "$ip")`. It's not a problem here, but for someone looking for a general method, this is not as good as @PM2Ring's answer with `printf`.

Comment: Ok. It should be easy to edit the sourced file, probably using sed. But we'll need to see the relevant code from that file to give more details. OTOH, there may be a better way to achieve what you _really_ want to do. So it's probably a good idea to start a new question.

Comment: This may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the `declare` command and indirect parameter expansion, but it's a little tricky to use with array names. It helps if you think of the index as *part* of the variable name, instead of an operator applied to the array name, like in most languages.

```
array0=(1 2 3 4 5)
arrayname=array0
name=$arrayname[3]
declare "$name=$ip"
echo "${!name}
```

Comment: It is a good trick, but you _do_ have to be sure that the contents of `name` are safe. Otherwise Bad Things can happen. Eg, try the above code but with `name=$arrayname[3]` replaced by `name=$arrayname[$(ls >&2;echo 3)]`. It still modifies `array0` as desired, but it also has unwanted side effects. :)

Comment: Well, that's an issue with setting the value of `name`, not `declare`.

Comment: Fair enough. I should've been more explicit about that.

Answer (score 2):

And yet another way to do it, this time using the versatile `printf`.

```
printf -v "$arrayname[3]" %s "$ip"
```

**demo**

```
#!/bin/bash

array0=(a b c d e)
echo "${array0[@]}"

arrayname='array0'
ip='127.0.0.1'

printf -v "$arrayname[3]" %s "$ip"
echo "${array0[@]}"
```

**output**

```
a b c d e
a b c 127.0.0.1 e
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
# declare -a arrayname=(element1 element2 element3)
# echo ${arrayname[0]}
  element1
# arrayname[4]="Yellow"
# echo ${arrayname[4]}
  Yellow
# export ip="192.168.190.23"
# arrayname[5]=$ip
# echo ${arrayname[5]}
  192.168.190.23
```

You don't have to use quotes.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

After initializing the arrays, you can access the array elements using their indices as follows.
Access as:

```
${arrayname[3]}
```

Comment: Have you understood what dncrft asked?

Comment: @Jdamian yes I just showed how to access the array element, which was wrongly accessed as shown in the example